# Rounding values

Tags: numerics, arithmetic

In *Mathematica* 8 when I enter `1 - 0.99 - 0.01` I get `8.67362*10^-18` instead of zero. How do I fix this problem?

I am getting imaginary solutions because of this error in my program.

Comment: Have a look at `Chop`.

Comment: When you input a number like 0.1 Mathematica will carry out computation using a [floating point approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) to the number, this is done in order to gain speed at the sacrifice of accuracy. If you desire exact numbers you can use rationals: `1-99/100-1/100 => 0`. Or you can simply account for approximation errors as b.gate suggest

Comment: Suggested reading: "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"

Comment: This is a very commonly asked about thing not only in Mathematica, but in just about any computer language.  In short, the reason is that these numbers are represented in binary (e.g. 1/2 is 0.1 in binary, 1/4 is 0.01), and not every number that's representable in decimal is representable in binary (similarly to how 1/3 = 0.3333... is not exactly representable in decimal with a finite number of digits).  E.g. when you type 1/10 = 0.1 in decimal, this is `0.1100110011001100...` in binary.  Because the machine works with a finite number of binary digits, precision suffers.

Comment: Without having more context, it's difficult to determine which of many possible solutions would work. For instance, in many cases a simple change of the form `N(1-99/100-1/100)` would do the trick.  Is this sort of solution acceptable or do you need some kind of automatic way to avoid floating point imprecision?

Comment: Voting NaRQ due to no response from the OP and no obvious way to answer the question as posed in any more detail than the suggestions already given above.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Do you think that questions that are answered in the comments should be closed as NaRQ? The question is clear enough and IMO doesn't need additional detailing from the OP. I suggest we wrap this up by putting all the comments in a community wiki answer. What do you think?

Comment: I think it's best closed as a dupe of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/8

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries no, of course not. I voted NaRQ in this case because it is not at all clear what kind of a "fix" the OP wants and despite many comments giving suggestions there has (as pointed out by @whuber) been no clarification as to which of these, if any, would be the basis of a useful answer. If you want to explain the ins and outs of IEEE754 along with all the implications of machine precision numbers in *Mathematica* then you'll get my upvote for sure, but otherwise, I really don't anticipate anyone volunteering to give such an epic answer to this question!

Comment: @Verbeia ditto, more or less. I doubt if indiscriminate `Chop`ping is really all that helpful for this issue in general; users would be better off having a proper understanding of how numbers are represented and then they can decide for themselves whether `Chop` is appropriate. But between the usual subtleties of floating point arithmetic (stemming from the fact that floats are actually rationals) and *Mathematica*'s own rather unique implementation of approximate reals, this is a massive undertaking. I'll drop a large bounty for a comprehensive answer but don't have time to write it myself.

Comment: `Rationalize[Unevaluated[1 - 0.99 - 0.01]]` or `RootApproximant /@ Unevaluated[1 - 0.99 - 0.01]` can be helpful.